# Is "Little Red Corvette" in a church mode?

Tags: chord-theory

I'm trying to make sense of the chord progression in [Litte Red Corvette](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pymb-PJzFAo) (Gb - Ab - Bb min - Gb).

The Ab maj chord is not in the key of Gb maj, giving the song a somewhat "exotic" sound to it. What is that? What key/mode would that be in?

Answer (score 3):

The song is actually in Db/C#. So the Gb chord is a IV. The sequence is IV, V I sometimes, and IV, V vi others. Putting it firmly into a major key. To help, try to establish which of the chords the song could finish on. It won't be the Gb, so that can't be the key, or 'I'.

Comment: the song seems to resolve to Gb in the verses, giving it a lydian sound. The chorus resovles to Db, which is a shift in modality.